# Predicate Logic Conclusion

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I want to show that $ A \vee B $ is a consequence of $ A \wedge B $.
So far I have tried some replacement rules so I could rewrite the premise (which is $ A \wedge B $) but I didn't figured it out.

Comment: This follows from the truth table / the definition of inclusive or. To get a more precise answer you probably need to give more background. What proof theory are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $A\land B$ you can infer $A$, and from $A$ you can infer $A\lor B$, so from $A\land B$ you can infer $A\lor B$.

Another way to think about it. The following are all tautologies, hence provable:
$$\begin{align}
&\vdash (A\land B)\to A \\
&\vdash A\to(A\lor B) \\
&\vdash (p\to q)\to((q\to r)\to(p\to r)) \tag{all instances are provable}
\end{align}$$

From these you can derive $(A\land B)\to (A\lor B)$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I have another exercise of that type. Can you please tell me if this is the right solution?
I have to show $ \neg(A \Rightarrow  B) \vdash A $  So my solution: $$ \neg( \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A) $$ $$ \neg ( B \vee \neg A)  $$ $$ \neg B \wedge A $$ $$ A \wedge \neg B \vdash A $$

Comment: Sure, that works.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help Brian.